# Sync folder from one fedora 15 server to another

Tags: php, linux, apache, ssh, fedora

On one server [s1] I for a page I create and resize one image into a 300x300 in one folder and [a thumbnail] 130x130 in a subfolder. s1 is a lamp server. I have another server [s2] running the same OS [fedora 15] serving static files [images, css, js] only, via nginx.

Is it possible to copy the images to s2 after they are created [resized, etc] from s1.?

This only happens maybe 10-20 times a day but needs to be immediate [if possible]. 
I've read about using php & sftp but I have been unable to make sense of it.

I guess my question, more to the point, is; Can anyone recommend a method that is reliable.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are in need of [rsync.](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/rsync/)

You can execute that command any way you want.

Have a look at few examples. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/rsync-command-examples/ (**not my blog** )

Comment: Thank you, Abhijeet Rastogi. Having a look now.

Comment: From what I see - I can run rsync with system() via php using a shell script after the images are created. Gonna give it a go when I wake up later today. Will report back the results.